# Showing null or nothing by fetching data from website with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

There is I want to fetch activeness of website and uptime data but only I can get is active but no uptime data. I do target the exact class of the website but show null. Can you please modify my code, where  I am doing something wrong. please help!

//Python code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import soupsieve
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
cosmos = "https://www.mintscan.io/cosmos/validators/cosmosvaloper1we6knm8qartmmh2r0qfpsz6pq0s7emv3e0meuw"
driver.get(cosmos)
time.sleep(8)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
driver.close()

uptime = soup.find('li', {'class': "InfoRow_container__2xTzg"})
uptime_dep = uptime.find('div', {'class': "InfoRow_value__1CHna"}).string
print(uptime_dep)

acitve = soup.find('div', {'class': "ValidatorInfo_statusBadge__PBIGr"})
para = acitve.find('p').string
print(para)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Selenium-based solution:**

You can use the below XPath:

```
//div[text()='Uptime']//following::div
```

to retrieve `Uptime` from the **HTMLDOM**.

**Code:**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

cosmos = "https://www.mintscan.io/cosmos/validators/cosmosvaloper1we6knm8qartmmh2r0qfpsz6pq0s7emv3e0meuw"
driver.get(cosmos)
time.sleep(8)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
#driver.close()

# uptime = soup.find('li', {'class': "InfoRow_container__2xTzg"})
# uptime_dep = uptime.find('div', {'class': "InfoRow_value__1CHna"}).string
# print(uptime_dep)

ele = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Uptime']//following::div")))
print(ele.text)

acitve = soup.find('div', {'class': "ValidatorInfo_statusBadge__PBIGr"})
para = acitve.find('p').string
print(para)
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output:**

```
97%
Active
```

Comment: Your Code is working for me. Thanks, i should explore more about expected_condtions

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd skip selenium and get the data from the api.

```
import requests

status_dict = {
    2:'Inactive',
    3:'Active'}

url = 'https://api.cosmostation.io/v1/staking/validator/cosmosvaloper1we6knm8qartmmh2r0qfpsz6pq0s7emv3e0meuw'
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()

uptime = 1 - (jsonData['uptime']['missed_blocks'] / jsonData['uptime']['over_blocks'])
status = jsonData['status']

print(uptime)
print(status_dict[status])
```

[image]

**Ouput:**

```
0.91
Active
```

Here's the json response:

```
print(jsonData)
{'rank': 38, 'account_address': 'cosmos1we6knm8qartmmh2r0qfpsz6pq0s7emv3um0vsa', 'operator_address': 'cosmosvaloper1we6knm8qartmmh2r0qfpsz6pq0s7emv3e0meuw', 'consensus_pubkey': 'cosmosvalconspub16adydsk7nw3d63qtn30t5rexhfg56pq44sw4l9ld0tcj6jvnx30sm7h6lm', 'bonded_height': 0, 'bonded_time': '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z', 'jailed': False, 'status': 3, 'tokens': '1034297369481', 'delegator_shares': '1034297369481.000000000000000000', 'moniker': 'Staked', 'identity': 'E7BFA6515FB02B3B', 'website': 'https://staked.us/', 'details': 'Staked operates highly available and highly secure, institutional grade staking infrastructure for leading proof-of-stake (PoS) protocols.', 'unbonding_height': '0', 'unbonding_time': '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z', 'rate': '0.100000000000000000', 'max_rate': '0.200000000000000000', 'max_change_rate': '0.020000000000000000', 'update_time': '2019-03-13T23:00:00Z', 'uptime': {'address': '7B3A2EFE5B3FCDF819FCF52607314CEFE4754BB6', 'missed_blocks': 9, 'over_blocks': 100}, 'min_self_delegation': '1', 'keybase_url': ''}
```

Comment: Sorry, but uptime on the website is 97% and your output is 1.0 and sir can you tell how you convert the whole site in JSON?

Comment: At that time, it was at 100% (1.0). That Uptime is not a static number, it's constantly being claculated base don the last 100 blocks. See my update to see that the data I pulled matches what is shown on the browser.

Comment: And I didn't convert the site to json. The site is dynamically rendered from the api. The api returns the data in the form of a json response, which is then used by the site to render it. I went after the data from it's source rather than having the browser render it. It's more efficient and robust to do it this way.

Comment: can you give me any source where i can learn the thing "dynamincally rendered from api" or any keyword so i can search on google. thanks for your response. i am new in python sorry if my questions feel like beginner questions.

Comment: sure. Give this a read [here](https://wpamelia.com/static-vs-dynamic-website/#:~:text=Static%20websites%20are%20ones%20that,databases%20in%20addition%20to%20HTML.). Google static vs dynamic sites will give you a plethora of sources.